# What happened after the final episode of Merlin?

Tags: merlin-bbc

In the final episode of *Merlin*,

> Leadership of Camelot passed to Gwen, due to Arthur's death. But without a strong king to win single combat challenges for the crown, did Camelot fall in an enemy's hands? Or did Gwen marry somebody else?

Comment: At the very end it's implied that Camelot is still in existance, though under another name, England. Though historically they were actually invaded by the Saxons and then taken away by the Saxon-Normand (Leader of the Norman Forces was a Saxon ex-heir) force during the battle of Hastings

Comment: @Oak Your comment is pretty close to an answer. Would you care to add it and maybe expand clarify which scene implies Camelot became England?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EaAMYwWgr6Q at 1:50, it's the part after Merlin throws the sword in the lake, then the scene has a transition to morden day (a truck passing), and if you notice it's the same location that Merlin was in.